# Pass services in a $scope function in angular

Tags: angularjs, scope, timeout

The model myApp is previously defined in an file app.js and the actual file synchro.js is recognized. 
I defined a controller, a service and an HTML page with function included in the controller.
The $scope.clearcache function in the Controller function did'nt recognize the services ($http,$timeout,..) an my personal service afficheModal too. 
If i put a console.log(afficheModal), it return: undefined.

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('SyncPointage.IndexController', Controller);

    function Controller($scope,$http,LS,$q,afficheModal,$rootScope,$timeout) {
        var vm = this;
        console.log('a',afficheModal)
        $rootScope.$on('us-spinner:spin', function (event, key) {
            $scope.spinneractive = true;
        });

        $rootScope.$on('us-spinner:stop', function (event, key) {
            $scope.spinneractive = false;
        });


         $scope.clearCache= function() {
            localStorage.removeItem('employees');
            localStorage.removeItem('working_profile');
            localStorage.removeItem('employee_working_profile');
            localStorage.removeItem('societes');
            localStorage.removeItem('etablissements');
            localStorage.removeItem('services');
            localStorage.removeItem('timestamp');
            var message = "Le cache est vid&eacute;";
            afficheModal.modal1($scope,$timeout,message)
        }
    }

})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-16 main center-block">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="clearCache()"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" fa-5x></i>&Eacute;tape 1 : Vider le cache</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="onLoad(readData)"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" fa-5x></i>&Eacute;tape 2 : Synchro Locale</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="lanceLocalData()"><i class="fa fa-database fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" fa-5x></i>&Eacute;tape 3 : Synchro Database</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Unclear code, since some code is missing. Can you provide a working Fiddle?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console? If so, please post it. In most cases there is an error in any angular related code and therefore the  variables aren't properly injected.

Comment: It's a part of my code because it's a very big project.
1) I define previously myApp module in a file app.js
2) My errors in the console are: 

angular.js:12477 TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal1' of undefined
    at Scope.Controller.$scope.clearCache (index.controller.js:39)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13322), <anonymous>:4:425)
    at callback (angular.js:23549)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15989)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16089)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23554)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)

Answer (score 0):

Services injected in controller are not available in the view unless you assign then to scope model. They are also not *"global variables"*

You have

```
ng-click="clearCache(LS,afficheModal)"
```

Both parameters are shown as injected services but they are not model properties

You stated that

Try

```
ng-click="clearCache()"
```

Comment: I correct in the html, it was a mismatch. In the  function Controller, i pass the parameters. function Controller     ($scope,$http,LS,$q,afficheModal,$rootScope,$timeout) {